# select one of two in this kind of format ()/()

Tags: python, regex, replace

In the text, this kind of format is there sometimes,
example.

```
/n I/ love (App)/(apple) because ...
```

after regex, string should be changed to like below.

```
I love apple because ...
```

every special character should be removed, and `(App)/(apple)`, this kind of format, I should select later.

using `)/(`, How can I take later??

thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `re.sub()` with capture groups. The pattern should match `(xxx)/(yyy)`, and use a capture group to get `yyy` and use it in the replacement.

Comment: I tried several times already and studing.

Comment: #print(tstr)
        tstr = re.sub('[?,!]', '', tstr)
        tstr = re.sub('\([^가-힣)]+\)', '', tstr)
        tstr = re.sub('\([^가-힣)]+\)', '', tstr)
        tstr = re.sub('\([^가-힣)]+[가-힣\s]+\)', '', tstr)
        tstr = re.sub('\([0-9]+[가-힣\s]+[0-9]+[가-힣\s]+\)', '', tstr)
        tstr = re.sub('\([0-9]+[가-힣\s]+[0-9]+\)', '', tstr)
        tstr = re.sub('\([0-9]+[가-힣\s]+[0-9가-힣\s]+\)', '', tstr)
        tstr = re.sub('\([가-힣]+[가-힣\s]+[0-9)]+\)', '', tstr)
        tstr = re.sub('\([가-힣]+[0-9a-zA-Z)]+\)', '', tstr)
        tstr = re.sub('\([가-힣\s]+[0-9)]+[가-힣\s]+\)', '', tstr)

Comment: this is my case,
but still there is a corner case, So I think I should just select second when this ()/() patten happened

Comment: Put your code in the question, not a comment

Answer (score 0):

```
\(\w+\)\s*\/\s*\((\w+)\)
```

try it! https://regex101.com/r/y268Mz/1

You can use `m.group(1)` to reference the second value in the pair.

Comment: I have to select second,
patter in the ( ) can be changed, there is no format of patter in the ( ).
should select second if there is ( ...)/(...) in the string.